# JQuery mobile 1.3.1 vs 1.4.5

Tags: jquery-mobile

i just want to know why if in include the jquery mobile 1.4.5, all my links didn t work. But if i include 1.3.1, the links works (but not my button on the left header).

here my website: [Fric-Afrique](http://fric-afrique.fr/news.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://fric-afrique.fr/ext/jquery_1.11.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://fric-afrique.fr/ext/jquery.mobile-1.4.5_new/demos/_assets/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

thank you for your help